# VueJs sending files to laravel (upload)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to upload multiple files but I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.
I may not be passing the correct files, or? It works okay when only sending one file, issue is when modifying the code for multiple files. (i'm new at this as well).

Here's my code:

```
 methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      this.filename = "";
      var names;
      var link;
      var keys = Object.keys(e.target.files);
      console.log(e.target.files);
      this.numberOfFiles = keys.length;
      console.log("# of files:"+this.numberOfFiles);
      if (keys.length <= 1) {
        this.filename = e.target.files[0].name;
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          if (e.target.files[i].size > 5000000) {
            console.log(e.target.files[i].name + " is too big.");
          } else {
            this.filename += e.target.files[i].name + ", ";

          }

        }
      }
      for (var i = 1; i <= this.numberOfFiles; i++) {
        this.file = e.target.files[i];
      }

      link = "localhost:8080/upload" + this.filename;

      console.log("names: "+names);


    },

    submitForm(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let currentObj = this;
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
            .content
        }
      };

      let formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 1; i <= this.numberOfFiles; i++) {
        formData.append('file['+i+']', this.file[i]);
        }

      //send upload request
      axios
        .post("/store_file", formData, config)
        .then(function(response) {
          currentObj.success = response.data.success;
          currentObj.failed = response.data.failed;
          currentObj.filename = "";
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          currentObj.failed = "No file attached.";
          console.log("No file attached");
        });
    }
  }
};
```

here is the html template:

```
<template>
  <b-card class="card" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <template>
      <div stlye="min-height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
        <Notification v-if="success !== ''" :text="success" />
        <Notification v-if="failed !== ''" :text="failed" />
      </div>
    </template>
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2>PDF upload</h2>
      <br />
      <div style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <form @submit="submitForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="text" autocomplete="off" />
              <input
                type="file"
                name="filename[]"
                class="custom-file-input"
                id="inputFileUpload"
                multiple
                v-on:change="onFileChange"
              />
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputFileUpload"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <p v-if="filename !== ''" class="text-danger font-weight-bold">Selected: {{filename}}</p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </b-card>
</template>
```

And this is the current output:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [1] => undefined
            [2] => undefined
            [3] => undefined
            [4] => undefined
        )

)
```

Comment: can you post the HTML of the template? Why do you start counting files from 1 in the loop? Do you have input name as  `file[]` or as `file[1]`?

Comment: @niklaz i added the html template, and no i don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When storing file data to the `file` property, in each iteration, you reset the previous assignment, instead of adding it as an array item to the `file`, so you should push it. Also, start iteration from 0, not from 1:

```
methods: {
  onFileChange(e) {
    this.filename = "";
    var names;
    var link;
    var keys = Object.keys(e.target.files);
    console.log(e.target.files);
    this.numberOfFiles = keys.length;
    console.log("# of files:" + this.numberOfFiles);
    if (keys.length <= 1) {
      this.filename = e.target.files[0].name;
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (e.target.files[i].size > 5000000) {
          console.log(e.target.files[i].name + " is too big.");
        } else {
          this.filename += e.target.files[i].name + ", ";

        }

      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numberOfFiles; i++) {
      this.file.push(e.target.files[i]); //push, don't assign 
    }

    link = "localhost:8080/upload" + this.filename;

    console.log("names: " + names);


  },

  submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let currentObj = this;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
          .content
      }
    };

    let formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numberOfFiles; i++) {
      formData.append('file[' + i + ']', this.file[i]);
    }

    //send upload request
    axios
      .post("/store_file", formData, config)
      .then(function(response) {
        currentObj.success = response.data.success;
        currentObj.failed = response.data.failed;
        currentObj.filename = "";
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        currentObj.failed = "No file attached.";
        console.log("No file attached");
      });
  }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way...
create a array call files, and try to push each file

```
v-on:change="onFileChange($event)"

onFileChange(e){
                Array.from( e.target.files).forEach(file => {
                    this.files.push(file);
                });
```

when passing

```
let formData = new FormData();
this.files.forEach(function (file) {
   formData.append('files[]', file);
 });
},
```